# Way to access error message in after_all hook

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm trying to access all the failed messages to create a notification when tests fail. Tried adding this:

```
def after_all(context):
    if context.failed == True:
        print('Why does none of this work?')
        print('stdout_capture length %d' % context.stdout_capture.len)
        print('stdout value: %s' % context.stdout_capture.getvalue())
        print('stderr_capture length %d' % context.stderr_capture.len)
        print('stderr value: %s' % context.stderr_capture.getvalue())
        print('context.log_capture.buffer: %s' % context.log_capture.buffer)
        for item in context.log_capture.buffer:
            print('this is a log message: %s' % item.getMessage())

def after_feature(context, feature):
    if context.feature.status == 'failed':
        logging.warning( context.feature.name)
```

And set an assertion to fail but the output at the end is always:

```
stdout_capture length 0
stdout value: 
stderr_capture length 0
stderr value: 
context.log_capture.buffer: []
```

Really feels like there should be an easy way to get a list of features or scenarios that failed to add to an email or webhook to make it more descriptive but feel like I'm missing something. What's the easiest way to access a list of things that failed in the after all step?

Answer (score 0):

Behave captures all exceptions that occur during a test run, in order to be able to keep going even after a given scenario has failed, meaning the exceptions are never really thrown. You can take a look at how it works in behave's source code, under `behave\model`, in the class `Step`.

One way to hook into this (which is what I did for one of my projects) is to monkey-patch store_exception_context

```
def store_exception_context(self, exception):
    self.exception = exception
    self.exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]
```

Personally I used the `before_step` hook to do this

```
def before_step(context, step):
    """This is executed before each step"""

    step.store_exception_context = store_exception_context_patch
```

Another way for what you are trying to achieve would be to simply generate results in any given output format, such as json, via Behave's running options, and then post-process the results output after the test run.

Comment: I would accept this answer if it explained how you access, `step.store_exception_context` in the after_all function.

Comment: I don't remember what I had done exactly, this is from an old project, but what you wanna do here is, as in my example replace the call to store_exception_context_patch in the before all, and then, your own replacement of it would store the relevant data somewhere else that you can retrieve in your after_all